# Server-side Polling using flask-socketIO

Tags: python, socket.io, client-server, flask-socketio

I have a client-server setup built around the flask-socketIO framework. One of the applications is that the server repeatedly polls a database, and lets the client know in case of updates. Here is a simple version of the code that I have:

The client code:

```
function poll(){
    socket.emit('pollForUpdates');
}

socket.on("update",function(msg){
    alert("Recieved update");
});
```

The server side code:

```
@socketio.on('pollForUpdates')
def pollForUpdates():
    event = threading.Event()
    k = ThreadJob(poll, event, 2)
    k.start()

class ThreadJob(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,callback,event,interval):
        '''runs the callback function after interval seconds

        :param callback:  callback function to invoke
        :param event: external event for controlling the update operation
        :param interval: time in seconds after which are required to fire the callback
        :type callback: function
        :type interval: int
        '''
        self.callback = callback
        self.event = event
        self.interval = interval
        super(ThreadJob,self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while not self.event.wait(self.interval):
            self.callback()


def poll():
    print "Polling at {}".format(datetime.now())
    socketio.emit("update")
    gevent.sleep(0)
```

The client fails to receive the updates that the server sends.

Comment: First of all, the `socketio.emit()` function will broadcast the event to all connected users, not just to the originating user. You need to add the client's room if you want only that client to be notified. Now regarding the main problem, are you sure your `poll()` callback function is invoked? If it is, I suggest you enable Socket.IO logging on the client and the server to see where is the message being dropped. Since you haven't shown the complete code there are some things I cannot check for you, but the logging should be helpful in finding where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At the moment, notifying all clients is not an issue. The callback is certainly invoked, as I see the debug print statements. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Okay. Any findings in the logs?